# Updating an existing Chrome tab instead of opening a new one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have created a Chrome extension which upon selecting text, offers a context menu link to Salesforce using the selected text:

```
function doSearch (search_target, tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.create( {
        url : "https://my.salesforce.com/apex/BR_caseRedirectDependingLicense?number="+search_target.replace(/\D/g,''),
        selected : true,
        index : tab.index + 1
    } );
}

function selectionHandler (info, tab)
{
    doSearch( info.selectionText, tab );
}

function resetContextMenus ()
{
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(
    function()
    {
            var id = chrome.contextMenus.create( {
                title: "Open in Salesforce",
                contexts: [ "selection" ],
            onclick: selectionHandler
        } );
    }
    );
}
resetContextMenus();
```

The intention here is to mark ticket numbers and open them in SF quickly, and it works perfectly.

However, I was wondering if it's possible to update an open salesforce tab instead of launching a new one every time.

I have tried looking around and encountered the following sample extension:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabs/inspector/

But it doesn't seem to work at all (perhaps because it's outdated).

I would much appreciate any help/guidance on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you can do it using the `chrome.tabs.update(..)` function, here is an example, this will update the tab in which your context menu item was clicked:

```
function selectionHandler (info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
        url : "https://my.salesforce.com/apex/BR_caseRedirectDependingLicense?number="+info.selectionText.replace(/\D/g,''),
        active : true
    });
}
```

If you want to first create a new tab and then keep updating it, you can use something like this:

```
let tabId = -1;
function doSearch (search_target, tab)
{
    const tabDetails = {
        url : "https://my.salesforce.com/apex/BR_caseRedirectDependingLicense?number="+search_target.replace(/\D/g,''),
        active : true,
        index : tab.index + 1
    };

    if (tabId == -1) {
        chrome.tabs.create(tabDetails, tab => {
          tabId = tab.id;
        });
    } else {
        // check if tab is still around
        chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab) => {
          if (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, tabDetails);
          } else {
            chrome.tabs.create(tabDetails, tab => {
              tabId = tab.id;
            });
          }
        });
    }
}
```

[Here is the chrome.tabs API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) beside this two examples, you may also want to look into [`chrome.tabs.query(..)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query), you can use that to find a specific tab.`

Also, in all these examples I've used `active` instead of `selected` because `selected` is deprecated.

Comment: ^ This opens the first tab with the error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: No tab with id: 462.

And additional link wont open nor refresh to the tab.

Comment: @Joey Which of the examples produces that error ? If it is the second one, have you included the `chrome.tabs.get(tabId, ...)` call ? That call makes sure that the tab still exists. The error message indicates that you're trying to update a tab that doesn't exist, I don't see any reason why any of the examples will produce that error.